# Taking Input from Python to Use in SQL query and return Results to screen

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have a python application where im trying to return results from a MSSQL database derived from the input entered into the python application

I have already connected to the SQL database and can return rows if I put in the row number.

```py
# Select IP
input_var = input("Enter IP Address: ")

def IP_Search():
    cursor.execute("SELECT IP, Location, Description, Project, OS, DNS, NETBIOS, MAC FROM [IPAM].[dbo].[Sheet1$] WHERE IP=(?)" (input_var)) 
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        while row: 
            print(IP_Search)
            row = cursor.fetchall()
```

I expect it to select the record that matches the ip address entered by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to account for sql injection attacks.

You need to format the string there are a few ways of doing that.

The current best practice in python is to use the new format strings. The f in front of the string lets python know that you want to format the string and `{input_var}` tells python that you want to replace that with the value of the variable input_var.

```
def IP_Search(input_var): 
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT IP, Location, Description, Project, OS, DNS, NETBIOS, MAC FROM [IPAM].[dbo].[Sheet1$] WHERE IP={input_var}") 
    row = cursor.fetchall() 
    while row:
        print (IP_Search)
        row = cursor.fetchall()

input_var = input("Enter IP Address: ")
IP_Search(input_var)
```

As pointed out in the comments however this leaves the database open to SQL injection attacks. You can see details for this here: https://bobby-tables.com/python

What you do instead is pass the variables to the `cursor.execute` function like this:

```
def IP_Search(input_var): 
    cursor.execute("SELECT IP, Location, Description, Project, OS, DNS, NETBIOS, MAC FROM [IPAM].[dbo].[Sheet1$] WHERE IP=%s", (input_var,)) 
    row = cursor.fetchall() 
    while row:
        print (IP_Search)
        row = cursor.fetchall()

input_var = input("Enter IP Address: ")
IP_Search(input_var)
```

Comment: ( cc: @errMSG ) re: "current best practice in python is to use the new format strings" - That may be true for string manipulation *per se*, but in this case it is being used to inject user input directly into a SQL statement and that is most definitely **NOT** a best practice. Search for "SQL Injection" or "Little Bobby Tables" for details.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for that Gord! Updating my answer.